# Sending delayed email from devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, devise

Is there a simple way of telling Devise to send all email via 
delayed_job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125564/rails-devise-delayed-job

Comment: for those looking for a straight forward anwser in 2019 check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56065247/8203251).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alternatively, instead of using the Delayed::Mailer gem, you can quite easily implement and use your own ActionMailer "delivery method", one that...

1. intercepts mail delivery from ActionMailer
2. stores the email in a table *(optional)*
3. creates a Delayed::Job that references the stored email
4. delivers the stored email when the delayed job is executed

Do something along the lines of:

```
# in config/application.rb
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :queued, Mail::QueuedDelivery

# in config/environment.rb (or one of the config/environments/*.rb files)
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :queued # ie. Mail::QueuedDelivery

# in lib/mail/queued_delivery.rb
module Mail
  class QueuedDelivery

    def initialize(values = {})
      # (optional)
    end

    def deliver!(mail)
      email = Email.create!(:delivery_handler => mail.delivery_handler.name, :message => mail.to_s)
      Delayed::Job.enqueue Jobs::Email::DeliverEmail.new(email.id)
    end

  end # class QueueDelivery
end # module Mail
```

The Delayed::Job you need to implement would then...

1. retrieve the stored email from the database -- `email = ::Email.find_by_id(email_id)`
2. deliver the email via the mail gem -- `Mail::Message.new(email.message).deliver`

That's it... hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what Devise is but I guess it is third-party gem you don't want to modify.
Try [delayed_job_mailer](http://github.com/andersondias/delayed_job_mailer). You can extend Devise mailers by monkey patching them to use delayed_job.

```
class SomeExistingMailer
  include Delayed::Mailer
end
```

or if you want to send all app emails via delayed job by default:

```
# config/initializers/delayed_mailer.rb
class ActionMailer::Base
  include Delayed::Mailer
end
```

Comment: I tried your 2nd suggestion which would be amazing if it worked, but got an error "/Users/bhellman/Sites/cline/config/initializers/delayed_mailer.rb:3: uninitialized constant Delayed::Mailer (NameError)"

Comment: This seems to me that Delayed mailer gem wasn't loaded. Did you specified it in Gemfile, eventually require it in environment.rb

Answer (score 2):

I found that none of the above worked for me. I'm using Devise 2.0.4 and Rails 3.2.2 with delayed_job_active_record 0.3.2

The way devise actually talks about doing something like this in the comments in the code is to override the methods in the User class. Thus, I solved it like so, and it works perfectly:

app/models/User.rb

```
def send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(self)
end
def send_reset_password_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.reset_password_instructions(self)
end
def send_unlock_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.unlock_instructions(self)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now the devise-async project which achieves exactly this:

- https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Send-devise-emails-in-background-(Resque,-Sidekiq-and-Delayed::Job)