# Rails - Send all emails with delayed_job asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asynchronous, devise, actionmailer

I'm using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and I'm very happy with it (especially with the [workless](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) extension).

But I'd like to set that **ALL** mails from my app are sent asynchronously.

Indeed, the solution offered for mailers

```
# without delayed_job
Notifier.signup(@user).deliver

# with delayed_job
Notifier.delay.signup(@user)
```

doesn't suit me because:

- it is not easily maintainable
- mails sent from gems are not sent asynchronously ([devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), [mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer))

I could use this kind of extension https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async but I'd rather figure out a solution for the whole app at once.

Can't I extend `ActionMailer` to override the `.deliver` method (like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316543/1620081 but it is 4 years old, like pretty much all the doc I found on the topic)?

I'm using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2 with activerecord.

Thanks for support

Comment: Have you tried your own suggestion? You'd have to override the Mail::Message object though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to write a utility method on the Notifier object as follows:

```
class Notifier

  def self.deliver(message_type, *args)
    self.delay.send(message_type, *args)
  end

end
```

Send the sign up email as follows:

```
Notifier.deliver(:signup, @user)
```

The utility method provides a single point where if needed you could replace delayed job with resque or sidekiq solutions.

Comment: I like it this way. Close to what I ended up doing, though I did not update here as it did not reply exactly the question "How to turn a whole mailer async by default?"

Answer (score 0):

If you have your ActiveJob and concurrency library set-up is done [documentation here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).The most simple solution is to override you device **send_devise_notification** instance methods involved with the transactions mails like shown [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Authenticatable#send_devise_notification-instance_method)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # whatever association you have here
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable
  after_commit :send_pending_devise_notifications
  # whatever methods you have here

 protected
  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    if new_record? || changed?
      pending_devise_notifications << [notification, args]
    else
      render_and_send_devise_message(notification, *args)
    end
  end

  private

  def send_pending_devise_notifications
    pending_devise_notifications.each do |notification, args|
      render_and_send_devise_message(notification, *args)
    end

    pending_devise_notifications.clear
  end

  def pending_devise_notifications
    @pending_devise_notifications ||= []
  end

  def render_and_send_devise_message(notification, *args)
    message = devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args)

    # Deliver later with Active Job's `deliver_later`
    if message.respond_to?(:deliver_later)
      message.deliver_later
    # Remove once we move to Rails 4.2+ only, as `deliver` is deprecated.
    elsif message.respond_to?(:deliver_now)
      message.deliver_now
    else
      message.deliver
    end
  end

end
```